# I configured the media directory, but I can not access the image under the media directory

Tags: python, django

I configured the media directory, but I can not access the image under the media directory:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/datadictionary/zfb.png

This is the setting in my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

My directories in project, you see there is a zfb.png there:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My DataDictionary model is bellow:

```
class DataDictionary(models.Model):
    appmodelfield = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)  # app_model_field
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, help_text="总的名称")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=32, help_text="内容")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/datadictionary/", null=True, help_text="图标")
    parentlevel = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True, help_text="父级")
```

You can see my `ImageField`, and I also pip installed the pillow.

And the django rest framework web browser response data is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "appmodelfield": null,
        "name": "支付类型",
        "content": "支付宝",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/datadictionary/zfb.png",
        "parentlevel": null
    }
]
```

You see the `image` field, it is indeed the directory image you see upper.

But I can not get the image in my browser.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Project `url.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is for Development environment only,when the `DEBUG=False` in your `settings.py`(in production environment),Django no longer handle static file and media file anymore,static file and media file will be handle by web server like apache etc.

Comment: Worth emphasising that this is for development only.

Comment: Thanks,I have update my answer.